# Mongoose $gte not filtering document after the current date

Tags: javascript, mongoose

My database fields:

```
// collection: jobs
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5899537dc5d86720b8cd1377"),
    "title" : "sssssssssssssssss",,
    "openings" : NumberInt("2"),
    "applyBefore" : ISODate("2012-12-21T00:00:00.000+05:45"),
    "employerId" : ObjectId("5898008a39b58b29c4de90dc"),
    "postedDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:41:29.606+05:45"),
    "__v" : NumberInt("0")
}
```

And my query to get the jobs after current `applyBefore` even if i use `Date.now()` it gives all the 
documents.

It should only show the documents after today's date by filtering `applyBefore` still no filter is happening

```
Job.find(filterArgs, {}, { applyBefore: { $gte: Date.now } }, (err, d) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a property named applyBefore

```
  filter.applyBefore = { $gte: new Date() };
    Job.find(filterArgs, (err, d) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(d);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ applyBefore: { $gte: Date.now } }` should be your query.

According to the official documentation (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), the first argument is the query itself.

You should use something like this:

`Job.find({ applyBefore: { $gte: Date.now } }, (err, d) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(d);
});`

Comment: yes that's true but, it works fine, but `filterArgs` is must that's the `query` filter for other condition

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't totally understand what you're saying. What is `filterArgs` and what do you use it for?

Comment: firstargument is always a query which is a `object`

Comment: Yeah, but so is `{ applyBefore: { $gte: Date.now } }`. In any case, you could do something like `var filterArgs = { applyBefore: { $gte: Date.now } }` if you want to use `filterArgs`.

Comment: `filterArgs` already contains some `keys` and `values` so, it cant be initialized again with new values, ideal method would by adding prop.

Comment: Got it! p0k8_'s answer is the way to go then. `filterArgs.applyBefore: {}` will do it.